# about tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5

I met a little problem when using this API.
`/biased does not exist or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?`
I guess that there is a difference when the tensorflow version update from 0.11 to 0.12.
By the way, a code, such as

```
def f(v):
    ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9)
    vema = ema.apply([v])
    return vema

with tf.variable_scope('s'):
    v1 = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[])
    v1 = v1 + 1
    f(v1)
with tf.variable_scope('s', reuse=True):
    v2 = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[])
    v2 = v2 + 2
    f(v2)
```

can normally run with tensorflow 0.11 but can't run with tensorflow 0.12 or higher version.
So, is there a method to solve this problem.